# How to change image size when nested in <p> tag

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to know how to change the size of an image when it is nested in a paragraph tag. The problem is that when nested in a paragraph, it won't take the values I set in the CSS for #3D1.
 My current HTML:

```
<p id="work3">
  <img id="3D1" src="img/photos/3D1.jpg">
</p>
```

My current CSS for the image:

```
#3D1{
  width:500px;
}
```

My current CSS for paragraph "work3":

```
#work3{
  font-size:17px;
  font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
  line-height:24px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color:#404040;
  text-align:justify;
  padding-left:10px;
  width:510px;
  height:332px;
}
```

All help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: While fiddling with the code in hopes of fixing it, I managed to find the problem. My problem was that I started the name of my ID with a number. Apparently, HTML and CSS don't sit well with that, and they just didn't "see" the properties of the images. In a way, I managed to fix the problem myself, but the ones who helped me were of great help! Thanks!

Comment: if you do enough search then you might not hav asked here

Comment: Change to *what*? And what is the problem? If you refer to an image by its `id`, it works whether it’s inside a `p` element or not.

Comment: I'll edit my question to clarify my case better.
EDIT: Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I just remember this.
just remove the number on your id/class name. I remember that its better not to start with a number if your naming a id/class. Just change "3D1" to "D1" maybe?

Comment: Doing that makes **all** the images on the website be that width. What I need is for the image with ID #3D1 in paragraph with ID work3 to be a specified width. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Did work, but it changes all the images in #work3. If I decide to add images of a smaller width later on, they will be really large. Do you know how to counter that problem?

Comment: I validated this answer because I believe it taught me the most, and to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3):

```
#3D1 {
  width:500px;
}

#work3 #3D1 {
  width: 510px;
}
```

Since you've defined the width through an id selector, you need to override the rule by  a selector with higher specificity (e.g. `p img { ... }` won't work)

Comment: That didn't work, but I tried using a class instead of an ID, which didn't work either... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
#work3 img{
   width:500px;
   height:200px;
}
```

this will make all images warped under the `<p>` tag with id `#work3`

Comment: That did work, but what if I have images of varying sizes? e.g The images I just had were perfect for this, but if I use an image that has a bigger height than width, how can I do it then?

Comment: @TobyvanKempen then you can avoid to specify the height

Comment: Syntax error: `width;500px` (in the answer and in a comment): must have colon `:` not semicolon `;` between the property and the value.

Comment: But won't it also take the width value if I specify the height value? e.g If I have an image that is 200px in width and 500px in height, won't it stretch it so it covers 500px in width and 200px in height?

Comment: Yeah, adding a height property with value made it look really weird :/